# Converge API - check if API is available

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using Converge API to transfer funds from Credit Cards to my merchant account in my system.

This is the API URL that I am using:
https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do

Sometimes I am having connectivity issues to the API and as a result, I am getting blank screens or similar errors.

Is there a way I can check if the API is available before I do the CCSALE transaction? This is a simple code I setup to try and achieve this task.

```
$url = 'https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//$result will be false if the CURL request fails.

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Instead or additionally of pre-checking if the api is available, you should handle a failure gracefully and show the user if something didn't work. Any amount of checking can still result in a failure if the specific endpoint stops working

Comment: @JensV, yes I was hoping I could redirect the user to a custom error page if the API is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the error info and then redirect the user. Use the code below to get a detailed response from CURL

```
$url = 'https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

//Tell cURL that it should only spend 10 seconds
//trying to connect to the URL.

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

//A given cURL operation should only take
//30 seconds max.

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);



$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) 
    $response = curl_error($curl);

echo stripslashes($response);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I have a question, do we need to add timeout in CURL code?

Comment: @BijuPDais Depends on your requirement. By default, 300 seconds is the connection timeout provided by CURL. If you want to modify it, check my updated code

Comment: Thanks. I will implement and let you know.